# No libpython found in expected location

Tags: python, installation, conda

I am trying to install LHAPDF for Madgraph3.5 on a linux server while in a conda environment. I ran:

wget http://www.hepforge.org/archive/lhapdf/LHAPDF-6.5.3.tar.gz -O- | tar xz

cd LHAPDF-6.5.3/

./configure --prefix=$PWD/../lhapdf_build
make -j4

There is a long string of output followed by "No libpython found in expected location None, exiting."

I found another stack overflow question with a similar issue that said to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/miniconda3/envs/mgenv/lib, where my libpython3.10.so.1.0 file is stored for my conda environment. I also tried the same thing while appending libpython3.10.so.1.0 to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Both produced the same error. I checked that I was using the right path by pip installing find-libpython and running find_libpython and it showed /usr/miniconda3/envs/mgenv/lib as the correct area. What else might be causing the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.